# Sum object in a column between an interval defined by another dataframe

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, sum, intervals

I am trying to obtain the sum of values of a column (B) based on the interval between two values on another column (A) in a "reference" dataframe (df):

```
A <- seq(1:10)
B <- c(4,3,5,7,5,7,4,7,3,7)
df <- data.frame(A,B)
```

I have found two ways of doing this:

```
y <- sum(subset(df, A < 3 & A >= 1, select = "B"))

> y
[1] 7
```

and

```
z <- with(df,sum(df[A<3 & A>=1,"B"]))
> z
[1] 7
```

However, I would like to do this based on a two vectors of values stored on another dataframe

```
C <- c(3,7,7)
D <- c(1,1,5)
df2 <- data.frame(C,D)
```

to obtain a column of y values for each pair of C and D values.

I have created a function:

```
myfn <- function(c,d) {
    y <-sum(subset(df, A < c & A >= d, select = "B"))
    return(y)
}
```

Which works fine with numbers

```
myfn(3,1)
[1] 7
```

but not with vectors.

```
myfn(c=C,d=D)
[1] 19

Warning messages:
1: In A < a :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In A >= b :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> myfn(df2$C,df2$D)

[1] 19
Warning messages:
1: In A < a :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In A >= b :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>
```

Does anyone have any suggestion about how I could calculate such interval for sequence of values?

Comment: In future, please use the "code" tool (`{}` button) rather than the block-quote tool to set off your code.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to do it. I will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
mapply(myfn, C, D)
# [1]  7 31 12
```

The problem is that your function is not naturally vectorized.  You can see that because your return value is a `sum` of the inputs, and `sum` is not a vectorized operation.

Beyond that, if you look at `myfn`, the expression `A < c & A >= d` doesn't make sense when `c` and `d` have more than one value.  There, you are comparing each value in `df` to the corresponding value in your `C` and `D` vectors (so first value to first, second to second, etc.), instead of comparing *all* the values in `df` to each value in `C` and `D` in turn.

**By using `mapply`, I'm basically looping through your function with as arguments a single value from `C` and `D` at a time.**

Fortunately in your case it turns out that `C,D` have different number of elements than `df`, so you actually got a warning.  If they were the same length you would not have gotten a warning and you would have gotten a single value answer, instead of the three you are presumably looking for.

There are better ways to do this, but the `mapply` approach is pretty trivial here and works with your code pretty much as is.

Comment: Many thanks BrodieG,

It worked a treat as you stated. And many thanks for explaining the reasons for not working. Now I understand the error.

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
is.between <- function(x,vec){  
  return(x>=min(vec) & x<max(vec))
}

apply(df2,1,function(x){sum(df[is.between(df$A,x),]$B)})
# [1]  7 31 12
```